# How to make Illustrator type tool selection automatically adapt with text length

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

So I'm learning Illustrator but when I try to use the type tool and write for example a long text, this will happen,[image: problem demo]

type tool won't automatically adapt with the text length and the same thing happens if I wrote one letter, the selection would be much larger than the letter so I have to adjust it manually when typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of making a text frame before typing the text, just click everywhere in the document with the **Text Tool** and write. 
Then you can transform this text line in a text frame clicking twice the circle icon at the right:

[image]